# how to send mail for log level ERROR in JBoss EAP6.1.0 (AS 7.2.0 Final Redhat 8)

Tags: jboss, smtpappender

Hi We are using JBoss EAP 6.1.0 for our project, i am trying to find a way to configure sending emails for loglevel `ERROR` in `standalone.xml` but i didn't fine any documentation which provides some example i added the below configuration to my `standalone.xml` but i am getting parsing exception after that.

Here is my code:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.2">
            <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
                [Some Code Here]
            </console-handler>
            <custom-handler name="EMAIL" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender" module="org.apache.log4j">
                <level name="ERROR"/>
                <formatter>
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n"/>
                </formatter>
                <properties>
                    <property name="BufferSize" value="10"/
                    <property name="SMTPHost" value="localhost"/>
                    <property name="From" value="sviswanadha@corelogic.com"/>
                    <property name="To" value="sviswanadha@corelogic.com"/>
                    <property name="Subject" value="SWS Error Log"/>
                </properties>
            </custom-handler>
            <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE">
                <formatter>
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <append value="true"/>
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
            <logger category="com.arjuna">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="sun.rmi">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="jacorb">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="jacorb.config">
                <level name="ERROR"/>
            </logger>           
            <root-logger>
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                    <handler name="FILE"/>
            <handler name="EMAIL"/>
                </handlers>                             
            </root-logger>
        </subsystem>
```

Exception I am getting:

```
JBAS014789: Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.2}handler-ref' encountered
```

Help in providing suggestions/solution is much appreciated.

Comment: Did HansElsen's suggestion fix the issue? Wondering if you could post the steps you took to fully implement Log4J SMTP Appender...

Answer (score 0):

JBoss AS 7 no longer uses log4j. It uses jboss-logging which seems to delegate to `ava.util.logging.Handler`s see also https://github.com/jboss-logging/jboss-logmanager/tree/master/src/main/java/org/jboss/logmanager/handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you already have the answer, but your xml is not valid.

```
<properties>
    <property name="BufferSize" value="10"/ <--- missing character
    <property name="SMTPHost" value="localhost"/>
    <property name="From" value="sviswanadha@corelogic.com"/>
    <property name="To" value="sviswanadha@corelogic.com"/>
    <property name="Subject" value="SWS Error Log"/>
</properties>
```